# Tag friend in wallpost with Android Facebook sdk

Tags: tags, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to tag a friend in a wallpost using the android facebook sdk. However, what is supposed to be the tag, is blank, nothing. This is the code I've used:

```
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            access_token = fb.getAccessToken();

            try {
                params.putString("format", "json");
                params.putString("access_token", access_token);
                String url = "https://graphs.facebook.com/me/friends";
                String response = Util.openUrl(url, "GET", params);
                JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                JSONArray array = json.optJSONArray("data");

                for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    String tempName = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                    String tempID = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");

                    //Probably should have some if-tests here

                    if(tempName.contains(*nameOfFriend*)) {
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("message", "App tagging test");
                        //this is where the tagging is supposed to happen
                        bundle.putString("tags", *UserID*);
                        try {
                            fb.request("me/feed", bundle, "POST");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tag-test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't find friend", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I've only granted the permission for "publish_stream", could it be that I need other permissions?
Thanks in advance for any help, guys!

Comment: Plasma please provide the solution for your question

Comment: @jyomin I never found a solution, unfortunately. Also, the code in my question is now outdated, as it's for the old facebook SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the working code to tag friends 
Also you have to submit your review to fb for the Taggable Friends api feature of the project you created in the devlepoer facebook account.After you get the approval for your submission the following code will tag your friends.

```
     Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
    params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
    params.putString("caption", ShareTripActivity.tripNotes); // text to post

    if(ShareTripActivity.arr_facebookID.size()>0)
    {
        String tagFriendListId="";
        for(int i=0;i<ShareTripActivity.arr_facebookID.size();i++)
        {

            tagFriendListId = tagFriendListId+"{'tag_uid':'"+ShareTripActivity.arr_facebookID.get(i)+"'} ,";

        }
        tagFriendListId=tagFriendListId.substring(0, tagFriendListId.length()-1);
         params.putString("tags","["+tagFriendListId+"]");

    }
   AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

//sample upload listener

public class SampleUploadListener extends BaseKeyListener implements RequestListener
    {

```
    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state)
    {
        try
        {
            // process the response here: (executed in background thread)
            Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Response: " + response.toString());
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            final String src = json.getString("src");

            // then post the processed result back to the UI thread
            // if we do not do this, an runtime exception will be generated
            // e.g. "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original
            // thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
        }
        catch (FacebookError e)
        {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public Bitmap getInputType(Bitmap img)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return img;
    }

    public int getInputType()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

In this arr_facebookID is the arraylist containing the facebook_user_id of your friends whom you are going to tag.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not working with facebook or android right now, so I can't verify that this works. But great job, I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t see any value for `place` in your code, but that is *required* when tagging people in posts made via the API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts:

> tags […] NOTE: You cannot specify this field without also specifying a place.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply! What are the customs for using places when tagging from an app? Do I have to create a place to check in (i.e. create a place and call it the same as the app itself) or should I retrieve physical location with altitude and longtidude? Or have I misunderstood completely? Do you have a code example available? Again, thanks for you reply!